# XCode - File not found

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart

tengo un proyecto de flutter, y cuando intento correrlo en mi Mac, aparece el siguiente error.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           11.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-04-12 22:39:29.707 xcodebuild[1930:19836] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-04-12 22:39:29.708 xcodebuild[1930:19836] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/vp/lfqwggg93lvdb_dw9bfxm5y80000gn/T/flutter_tools.8h63g4/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirggbx91/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/victorolave/Documents/dev/artndigital/imegine/imegine-flutter-mobile-app/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/plugins/openpgp/ios'
    ld: file not found: /Users/victorolave/Documents/dev/artndigital/imegine/imegine-flutter-mobile-app/ios/.symlinks/plugins/openpgp/ios/libopenpgp_bridge.a
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/vp/lfqwggg93lvdb_dw9bfxm5y80000gn/T/flutter_tools.8h63g4/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirggbx91/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Error (Xcode): File not found: /Users/victorolave/Documents/dev/artndigital/imegine/imegine-flutter-mobile-app/ios/.symlinks/plugins/openpgp/ios/libopenpgp_bridge.a

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

He probado de todo limpiar el proyecto tanto con flutter, como con pod, actualice xCode, y muchas cosas más que he encontrado en internet, pero el error sigue siendo el mismo.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: y tambien en ocaciones busca el archivo. libopenpgp_bridge.a en un path que corresponde al equipo de un compañero.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mismo me sucedió, incluso actualice el xcode pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error, era una app que ya la visualizaba, pero al intentar volver a abrir surgió el mensaje. (estuve implementando mapbox dentro de la app antes de que sucediera)